# OpenType Stylistic Sets with a Canvas element

Tags: css, html, canvas, webfonts, opentype

I am trying to use an OpenType font with an alternate stylistic set to draw to a canvas element. I have it working with the standard html and fonts with

```
font-feature-settings: "ss01";
```

However, I also need to write the font to a canvas element. Is there anyway to do this? Or is this not supported?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not supported. Canvas does not get the same text engine control that CSS3/CSS4 offers HTML. Canvas's `ctx.font` only takes CSS [`font` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font), which does not have provisions for `font-feature-settings` as part of the condensed format. You *might* be able to somehow work in [font-variant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant) but I never tried that, so you'd have to look this up yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As of right now you still can't, not with `font-feature-settings` nor with `font-variant`, and for that matter it's not even in the specification yet for Canvas.

But it might be someday: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/592